# Running sed on string, benefit of using "echo" + "pipe" over "<<<"

Tags: bash, sed, io

Commonly I see people manipulating strings using sed as follows:

```
echo "./asdf" | sed -n -e "s%./%%p"
```

I recently learned I can also do:

```
sed -n -e "s%./%%p" <<< "./asdf"
```

Is there a reason to avoid the latter?
For instance, is it bash-specific behaviour?

Comment: `<<<` is only available in newer versions of bash, so if you care about portability and backward-compatibility then you might want to use the first method. (From [Wikipedia entry for bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Features): "Since version 2.05b Bash can redirect standard input (stdin) from a "here string" using the <<< operator.")

Comment: `<<<` has been in `bash` for a long time; the main concern is portability with POSIX rather than other versions of `bash`.

Comment: If portability were a concern, would it not be better to use `printf` rather than `echo`?  My understanding `echo` implementations vary more, than those of `printf`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Didn't want to get into the nitty-gritty details of implementation level, just wanted to suggest a point on the byte level representation.

Comment: @Fred, definitely a very good point; [POSIX echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) has a lot of leeway in its specification, as the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE parts of the spec make clear.

Comment: @BenjaminW., hmm. If that question didn't digress into unrelated content (kept itself scoped to its title), it'd be a tighter dupe.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually prefer the answers here anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### How should I trim `./` from the beginning of a path (or perform other simple string manipulations)?

Bash's built-in syntax for this is called [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). `${s#./}` will expand `$s` with any leading `./` trimmed internal to the shell, with no subprocess or other overhead. [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) covers many additional string manipulation operations.

---

#### What are the differences between `echo "$s" | ...` and `... <<<"$s"`?

1. Portability

   As you've noted, `<<<` is not available in POSIX sh; this is a ksh extension also available in bash and zsh.

   That said, if you need portability, the multiline equivalent is not far away:

   ```
   ... <<EOF
   $s
   EOF
   ```
2. Disk usage

   As currently implemented by bash (and as an implementation detail subject to change), `<<<` creates a temporary file, populates, it, and redirects from it. If your `TEMPDIR` is not on an in-memory filesystem, this may be slower, or may generate churn.
3. Process overhead

   A pipeline, as in `echo foo | ...`, creates a *subshell* -- it forks off a completely new process, responsible for running `echo` and then exiting. When you're running `result=$(echo "$s" | ...)`, then that pipeline is itself in a subshell of your parent shell, and *that* shell has its output read by the parent.

   Modern unixlikes go to significant effort to make `fork()`ing off a subprocess low-overhead to the extent possible, but even then it can add up when in an operation done in a loop -- and on platforms such as Cygwin it can be even more significant.
4. `echo` bugs

   Last but not least -- `<<<"$s"` will represent any contents of the variable `s` precisely, with the exception that it can add a trailing newline. By contrast, `echo` has a great deal of leeway in its specified behavior: It can honor backslash expansions or not depending on compliance with the optional XSI extensions to the standard (and presence or lack of the widespread but entirely noncompliant extension of `-e`, and/or runtime flags that disable it); the ability to avoid addition of trailing newlines with `-n` is not guaranteed by the standard; &c. Even if you're using a pipeline, it's better to use `printf`:

   ```
   # emit *exactly* the contents of "$s", with no newline added
   printf '%s' "$s" | ...

   # emit the contents of "$s", with an added trailing newline
   printf '%s\n' "$s" | ...

   # emit the contents of "$s", with '\t', '\n', '\b' &c replaced, and no added newline
   printf '%b' "$s" | ...
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed` at all is not desirable if it can be helped (see Charles Duffy's answer); put the string in a variable and let the shell do it with POSIX-compatible parameter expansion.

```
$ s="./asdf"
$ echo "${s#./}"
asdf
```

Comment: Good comment that is relevant to my example. However, it was merely a "dummy" example, the real regular expressions can not be replaced by parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things at play here.

1. <<< vs. pipelines
2. `sed` (or other external command) vs parameter expansion

If you can do something with expansion, it is very likely it will be much quicker, as it saves an external command being launched.

However, not everything can be done with expansion.  So you may have to use an external command and use as input something you have in a variable.  In this case, you will have to make your choice based on portability considerations.  As for performance, if it matters, you should probably test in your context what performs best.