# UNIX change all the file extension for a list of files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am a total beginner in this area so sorry if it is a dumb question.

In my shell script I have a variable named FILES, which holds the path to log files, like that:

```
FILES="./First.log ./Second.log logs/Third.log"
```

and I want to create a new variable with the same files but different extension, like that:

```
NEW_FILES="./First.txt ./Second.txt logs/Third.txt"
```

So I run this command:

```
NEW_FILES=$(echo "$FILES" | tr ".log" ".txt")
```

But I get this output:

```
NEW_FILES="./First.txt ./Secxnd.txt txts/Third.txt"
#                                   ^^^
```

I understand the `.` character is a special character, but I don't know how I can escape it. I have already tried to add a `\` before the period but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` replaces **characters** with other characters. When you write `tr .log .txt` it replaces `.` with `.`, `l` with `t`, `o` with `x`, and `g` with `t`.

To perform **string** replacement you can use `sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'`, where `s` means *substitute* and `g` means *globally* (i.e., replace multiple times per line).

```
NEW_FILES=$(echo "$FILES" | sed 's/\.log/.txt/g')
```

You could also perform this replacement directly in the shell without any external tools.

```
NEW_FILES=${FILES//\.log/.txt}
```

The syntax is similar to `sed`, with a global replacement being indicated by two slashes. With a single slash only the first match would be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is not the tool you need. The goal of tr is to change characters on a 1-by-1 basis. You probably did not see it, but `Second` must have been changed to `Secxnd`.

I think `sed` is better.

```
NEW_FILES=$(sed 's/\.log/.txt/g' <<< $FILES)
```

It searches the `\.log` regular expression and replaces it with the `.txt` string. Please note the `\.` in the regex which means that it matches the dot character `.` and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the response, may I ask what does the <<< does?

Comment: This is called a Here String https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html it gives the string as an input to your command line. If you want to know more about `command <<< $variable` vs. `echo "$var" | command` please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116343/whats-the-difference-between-here-string-and-echo-pipe